# Need PhpMyAdmin download with PHP 5.2 +

Tags: php

Give me the download link for PhpMyAdmin.

I uploaded into domain. But its required php 5.2 +.

please give me the download link for PhpMyAdmin with PHP 5.2 +

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @vijai: google is your friend ....

Comment: I won't downvote just hurting my reputation ......

Comment: What exactly is it you need? Do you need a phpMyAdmin version that works with PHP 5.2?

Comment: yes need phpMyAdmin version that works with PHP 5.3 download link.

Comment: It is really hard to understand you.

Comment: that 3.3 is working with PHP 5.2 and 5.3

Comment: @Kugel: +1 really hard to understand what he wants ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vijai the `PHP 5.2 +` means it working with PHP 5.2 and all **later** versions.

Answer (score 2):

here you go... i guess ;)

[PHPmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php)

Comment: Rage7 i tried some downloads. but its not suppoting, thats y asking. All links Version compatible with PHP 5 and MySQL 5.

Comment: you have PHP 5 ok I will get you a link

Comment: @vijai: I have just downloaded the phpMyAdmin3.0.1 and it's already 5.2 version so you have to stick with version 2 or upgrade your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

PhpMyAdmin 4.1+  require PHP 5.3+

Download http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/files/phpMyAdmin/3.5.8.2/phpMyAdmin-3.5.8.2-all-languages.7z/download is compatible PHP 5.2